# dockerfile, how to support docker run options -d, -v and -p?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a very simple dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ADD node-v6.11.1 /usr/local
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
RUN node -v
COPY server /server
RUN cd /server && npm install
EXPOSE 80 443
VOLUME ["/server/public"]
CMD cd /server && node server
```

`sudo docker run server` works as expected.

`sudo docker run server -v /public:/server/public` results in:`starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

`sudo docker run server -d` results in:
`starting container process caused "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

`sudo docker run server -p 80:80` gives similar error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the options before the image name as follow:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

For example:

```
sudo docker run -v /public:/server/public server
```