# Unable to run shell in my container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I want to dockerize my application and I want to run and enter my container in order to see whether packages were installed properly, files were copied, etc.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.6
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY .*.json .
COPY src/ .
USER node
RUN yarn global add @angular/cli
EXPOSE 4200
```

The problem is, I can't run my container via `docker run`:

```
docker run my-notes -it --rm ash
```

I see errors:

```
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to pass the docker options before the image name not after that:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186522/dockerfile-how-to-support-docker-run-options-d-v-and-p/45186594#45186594) as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also `ash` doesn't exist in the `node` image

Comment: That was my problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `node` image comes with `sh`, `bash` and `dash`.

If you want `ash` you can install the package, but it's just a symlink to `/bin/dash` so you can just run:

```
docker run -it --rm my-notes dash
```

To install the `ash` package, add the following to your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN set -uex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install ash; \
    apt-get
```

Then `ash`/`dash` can be run with

```
docker run -it --rm my-notes ash
```